# Trouble Passing a Value Through Intent to new Activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

So i'm struggling a bit here to get the values from one activity passed to another. I've tried everything and have looked elsewhere here, but everything I've found didn't work or was unrelated to my issue.

I'm instantiating the intent and using Extras to pass the value. I'm using Eclipse and it's not giving any errors in the IDE.
According to LogCAT, it's a NullExceptionPointer Error getting thrown out as i'm using the getIntExtra() method of the intent.

Here's the code from Main Activity:

```
int tempScore = GUESS_COUNT;
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SubmitScore.class);
intent.putExtra("PASSED_SCORE", tempScore);
startActivity(intent);
```

And here's the code from the new activity:

```
private Intent i = getIntent(); //declared in the class header
tempScore = i.getIntExtra("PASSED_SCORE", 999); //exists inside of a private method for the class 
//(ALSO: THIS tempScore is a private int variable localized to only this class, so that's not the problem)
```

The moment it tries to store the getIntExtra() returned value to tempScore, it throws the NullPointerException error. Meaning: it's trying to pull a value where there is none.
Shouldn't it push 999 as the default value at least though? Why the Error instead? Also, why did the value not getting pushed to the new activity? Thanks in advance for your help.
JRad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> private Intent i = getIntent(); //declared in the class header

FYI, there is no intent available at that time so you can't use `getIntent()`. Instead, declare it inside the `onCreate()`.

Comment: This KINDA the answer actually. While not 100%, it put me in the right direction. You're right, onCreate() has to happen before it can actually pull the Intent. (Which Eclipse doesn't pick up on interestingly enough). Unfourtunately, you can't put it inside of a method like onCreate because it won't recognize that it will execute before the method that encapsulates getIntExtra(). My solution was to place getIntent() inside of the same method since it's the only place i'm currently using the pushed values. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to check first that you are passing Intent is not null like:

```
if(i.getExtras()!=null)
{
    tempScore = i.getExtras().getString("PASSED_SCORE");
}
```

Comment: Checking doesn't matter. It IS null when I previously passed a value. I don't care about the error, I care that it's null.

Comment: ok then pareshMayani's answer is very well explained in short. +1 for him.